# MongoDB refusing connections at random

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have been facing this issue with mongodb 2.4 and now with mongodb 2.6 as well. I use apache, php 5.4, mongodb driver 1.4.5.
I have modified ulimit and also added 99-mongodb-cproc.conf to /etc/security/limits.d/ with

```
*       soft    nproc    64000
root    soft    nproc    64000
root    hard    nproc    unlimited
```

I have CSF installed and already tried disabling it. Checked the network ping, ping time is less than .0200ms.

This is a replica set with three servers. One primary, second replica and third arbiter.
I have tried making connections **PrimaryPreffered** **SecondaryPreffered** and **Primary**.
*(Out of these configs Primary works best for me.)*

**Out of every 5 connections I make 1 fails. And this is completely random. I can't predict or find any trend to predict this failure.** The time connection fails at random, there are about 140-142 connections on the mongodb. That's not too much I suppose.

*Server is strong enough to support good bandwidth and has 64 Gigs of RAM.*

I tried pulling down all the scripts and services writing or reading to mongodb. Still the issue persists. When the connection fails there is no load at server, there is no heavy usage of RAM.

I use PHP MongoDB Driver and I am skeptical about it too.

I use mongoDB for production and have gone through the production notes as well.
Apart from *atime* all has been taken care of. *Atime* will not have a lot to do with creating connection I believe.

After a long fight for over 50 hours I need help from the community on this, maybe I have overlooked something? Please Help me with this issue!

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Include messages from the server logs and from the PHP driver.

Comment: Error Code is 111, message being the same as I stated above: "Connection Refused". Status of server is stable during this, a normal operation write locks of 4-8%, and no page faults occurring. Its really an odd behavior. I have checked kernel logs, they don't have anything in specific. I cant even point out the exact time this occurs because its completely random. The product is in production.. really need help for this..

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the actual, full text of the error messages and some snippet of the log around when it occurred? Do you have any other problems with your network? It could be your network dropping connections. Have you tried with a client besides the PHP driver? Do you see connections being dropped e.g. with the mongo shell?

Comment: Sorry for replying late (1 year late) on this, but this kept on happening to us for long. Eventually, we brought down the replica set and initiated the production in standalone mode. It worked well. I did keep on researching why this happened, seems like there was no issue with the network so I checked the driver as you suggested, that time we were using mongo driver less than 1.3 when we upgraded to latest stable release it was sorted. Thanks for your support! And sorry for late reply!